# Efficiently find which group matched in a RegExp search

Tags: javascript, regex

When my `RegExp` has a number of capturing groups, I want to know which group made the capture (or at least the first/last such group, if there were more than one). If you're familiar with Python, this is basically the equivalent of `re.MatchObject.lastgroup`. Some code to make it clearer:

```
var re_captures = new RegExp("(\\d+)|(for)|(\\w+)", "g");
var str = " for me 20 boxes please";
var result;

while ((result = re_captures.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(result[0], 'at', result.index, result.slice(1));
}
```

It prints:

```
for at 1 [ undefined, 'for', undefined ]
me at 5 [ undefined, undefined, 'me' ]
20 at 8 [ '20', undefined, undefined ]
boxes at 11 [ undefined, undefined, 'boxes' ]
please at 17 [ undefined, undefined, 'please' ]
```

The `result` array shows which groups made a capture, but I see no way to quickly find out for each given match, which group matched *without iterating through the array*. This comes useful in cases where large regexes are built programmatically and iterating is inefficient.

Am I missing something obvious, or isn't it possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But what exactly are you doing when this becomes inefficient? There might be a better solution than large regexes with large results.

Comment: @Bergi: re my use, see the longish comment I made to minitech's answer below.

Comment: I know this is cheating, but you can use `indexOf` to avoid iteraring explicitly. Sure, the engine will iterate internally

Comment: @Pumbaa80: `indexOf` what? There is no `indexOfNot`.

Comment: @EliBendersky: I see. I think I'd go with single regexes, execute all of them and put them in a queue sorted by match indices. The generator would shift the first item and re-execute the respective regex to re-insort the next result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re not missing anything; iterating through the array is the only way.

How many groups could there be that iterating through the matches is actually a performance problem? If you don’t need a group, you can always make it non-capturing, but…

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Re performance: I have a use case where I create a pretty long regex with dozens of groups. Since this part of the code is performance sensitive, it's a shame to have to iterate over an array for every single match. If you're really curious see - https://gist.github.com/eliben/5797351 - it's a regex based lexer, and it tucks everything into one huge regex. It also uses named groups, but that isn't necessary. Knowing which group matched *is*, though.

Comment: @EliBendersky: You could make a different regular expression for each and check if each one matches each time. I don’t think it would be any faster, though. I usually parse stuff “manually” in JavaScript, but that doesn’t work if you’re trying to make it generic, huh? =P

Comment: +1, I would probably have used multiple regexes here. I wonder can't this (not yours, the one of OP) task be divided even better, collecting all the tokens of some category at first run, then collecting all the others afterwards.

Comment: Yep, using separate regexes was the original way this was done and their merging sped things up (the iteration moved to the C level of regex implementation); I assume the same benefit would apply to the JS code, though perhaps to a lesser degree. Anyhow, without quick identification of the matching group, the "merge regexes into a big one" trick won't work :-/

Comment: @EliBendersky: Have you benchmarked iterating the result array?

Comment: I have not benchmarked the JS code yet. Just encountered this problem when porting my Python code and wondered if there's a solution. However, given a few dozen regex rules, I think the array iteration will definitely kill performance. That said, this all is mainly of academic interest, so I might do some benchmarking just for fun at some point :)